Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied in MAUI Android
In my MAUI multi-project app, I am loading an external URL using the Maui's WebView, that page has an option to record audio. I have created a custom handler for this functionality, and it is being called; however, I am encountering a permission error.
Shared project code
 public class WebPagewithMenuItem : ContentPage
   {

       private static string title = "";
       private static string hostUrl = "";
       private readonly CustomWebView browser = new CustomWebView();

       public WebPagewithMenuItem(string url, string token, string pageName, string hostUrlString)
       {
           title = pageName;
           hostUrl = hostUrlString;
           var html = setHtml(url, token);

           switch (DeviceInfo.Platform)
           {
               case var value when value == DevicePlatform.WinUI:
                   break;

               case var value when value == DevicePlatform.iOS:
                   break;

               default:
                   browser.Source = html;
                   browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;
                   browser.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetEnableZoomControls(true).SetDisplayZoomControls(true);
                   Content = browser;
                   break;
           }
       }

       private void Browser_Navigating(object? sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
       {
           var args = new DecisionHandlerDelegate();
           args.Cancel = e.Cancel;
           args.Uri = e.Url;
           WebView_OnNavigationStarted(sender, args);
       }

       private HtmlWebViewSource setHtml(string url, string token)
       {
           var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
           {
               Html = @"
                       <style>
                           .loader {
                             border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
                             border-radius: 50%;
                             border-top: 4px solid #3498db;
                             width: 40px;
                             height: 40px;
                             -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
                             animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                               position: absolute;
                               left: calc(50% - 20px);
                               top: calc(50% - 20px);
                           }

                           /* Safari */
                           @-webkit-keyframes spin {
                             0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                             100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
                           }

                           @keyframes spin {
                             0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                             100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
                           }
                       </style>
                       <div class='loader'></div>
                       <form action='" + url + @"' method='post' target='_self' id='formIframe' style='display: none'>
                           <input type = 'hidden' name = 'token' value = '" + token + @"'>
                           <input type = 'submit' value = 'Do Stuff!'/>
                       </form>
                       <script>
                               document.getElementById('formIframe').submit();
                       </script> "
           };

           return html;
       }

       private async void WebView_OnNavigationStarted(object? sender, DecisionHandlerDelegate e)
       {
           string uriLower = e.Uri.ToLower();
           if (!uriLower.Contains("data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64"))
           {
               if (uriLower.Contains("/externalauth/authaccess") == false && uriLower.Contains("/externalauth/mobilehost") == false && e.Uri.Contains("file:///") == false && e.Uri.Contains("about:blank") == false && uriLower.Contains("/help") == false && uriLower.Contains("errors/mobileerror") == false && uriLower.Contains("security/login") == false && uriLower.Contains("mvc=0") == false)
               {
                   string urlValue = (System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(e.Uri)).Replace(hostUrl, "..");
                   string newPageURL = "";
                   newPageURL = hostUrl + "/externalauth/mobilehost?url=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(urlValue);

                   switch (DeviceInfo.Platform)
                   {
                       case var value when value == DevicePlatform.WinUI:
                           break;

                       default:
                           var webview = (Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView)sender;
                           if (webview != null)
                           {
                               webview.Source = newPageURL;
                           }
                           break;
                   }
               }
               else if (uriLower.Contains("errors/mobileerror"))
               {
                   MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                   {
                       Navigation.RemovePage(this.Navigation.NavigationStack[this.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
                       Navigation.PopAsync();
                   });
    
                   e.Cancel = true;
                   browser.IsVisible = false;
               }
               else if (uriLower.Contains("security/login"))
               {
                   MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                   {
                       Navigation.RemovePage(this.Navigation.NavigationStack[this.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
                       Navigation.PopAsync();
                   });

                   e.Cancel = true;
                   browser.IsVisible = false;
               }
           }
       }

    

       private void WebPagewithMenuItem_ChildRemoved(object? sender, ElementEventArgs e)
       {
           switch (DeviceInfo.Platform)
           {
               case var value when value == DevicePlatform.WinUI:
                   var mainPage = ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage);
                   if (mainPage != null)
                   {
                       mainPage.ToolbarItems.Clear();
                   }
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
           }
           ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).ChildRemoved -= WebPagewithMenuItem_ChildRemoved;
       }
   }

CustomWebView
  public class CustomWebView : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView
  {
      
  }

In Android Side.....
   public class CustomWebViewHandler : WebViewHandler
   {
       protected override void ConnectHandler(Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
       {
           base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

           // Enable JavaScript and configure other settings
           platformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
           platformView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
           platformView.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
           platformView.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
       }

       protected override void DisconnectHandler(Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
       {
           platformView.SetWebChromeClient(null);
           base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
       }
   }

   public class CustomWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
   {
       public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
       {
           // Check if microphone access is included in the request
           if (request.GetResources().Contains(PermissionRequest.ResourceAudioCapture))
           {
               request.Grant(request.GetResources()); 
           }
           else
           {
               base.OnPermissionRequest(request);
           }
       }
   }

MainActivity.cs
 protected async override void OnResume()
 {
     try
     {
         base.OnResume();

         PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();

         if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
             await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
    }
 }

Registered in MauiProgram in Android side
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

        builder
            .UseSharedMauiApp()
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>
            {
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewHandler));
            });
        return builder.Build();
    }
}

I have also added the permissions to AndroidManifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />


I can't create a sample to reproduce your problem because you didn't provide the full code about IPhoneFeatureService , DecisionHandlerDelegate and WebView_OnNavigationStarted(sender, args);.

And did the error message say what permission was denied?

[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied", source: https://www......
Microphone permission . External page can be anything with audio recording feature.

Could you please provide the missed code so I can create a sample to test?

I have updated the WebPagewithMenuItem class

Still missed the DecisionHandlerDelegate class.

public class DecisionHandlerDelegate
{
public string Uri { get; set; }
public bool Cancel { get; set; }
public bool OffloadOntoDevice { get; set; }
}

The WebPagewithMenuItem 's constructor has 4 parameters, how should I create it to test.
